# gitのプロジェクトがインポートできません

Tags: git, eclipse

URLは正しいですが、
できないので何が問題なのか気になります。
もしかして、分かる気がするお方はお願いいたします

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

![画像の説明をここに入力][2]

Comment: 上のスクリーンショットでマスクしているURLが下のスクリーンショットで見えているような気がするのですが、問題ないのでしょうか。

Comment: http ではなくて https ではないでしょうか？

Comment: URLが正しいことは、どうやって確認しましたか? また、エラーログの内容を共有すると解決策が見つかりやすいと思います。

Comment: ダイアログの裏にちらりとみえているgitのエラーが「invalid advertisement of <!DOCTYPE html～」なので、やっぱりURLが違うんじゃないでしょうか。URL出てしまってるの私も気になりますね。

Answer (score 2):

この様な場合、`git ls-remote` を使うと remote repository の状態を確認することができます。

```
$ git ls-remote http://dev....git
fatal: http://dev....git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

$ git ls-remote https://dev...git
(No reply ...)
```

https の方は認証の関係でしょうか、応答が返りませんね。

Answer (score 0):

他の方が作成されたプロジェクトページを見てみましたが( http://dev.naver.com/projects/beavertoy/src 等)、 http でなく https を指定するのが正解でしょう。